# "still too young" vs "far too young"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He's **still too young** to get married.
>
> He's **far too young** to get married.

What's the difference between these two sentences? I know that "far" is "very much", but I want to understand the meaning correctly. When is it commonly used in this context? For example, the first sentence is used, when "he" is 16-17 years old, but the second one is used, when "he" is 10-15 years old. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct. (I would say _could be used_ - some people might well consider that a person was too young to get married at 18+, even though it would be legal!)

Comment: You are right. Also if you replace "young" with "immature", or "inexperienced" (which is sometimes implied by the word), you can apply both sentences to a person, let's say, in their 30s, who is legally allowed to marry, physically mature, but who still lacks worldliness or other qualities (culturally) required for marriage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Still** implies "not yet", or that something will change.  **Far** is simply about the amount.

In your case, both could be appropriate, but there are other cases where only one might be.  For example, I am *far* too short to play professional basketball, but if I said I were *still* too short, that implies that I think I will grow more.